# Java реализовать хранение документа и табличной части как в 1С

Tags: java, структуры-данных

Java реализовать хранение документа и табличной части как в 1С
Задача:

- есть таблица с товарами.
- нужно сделать документ в табличную часть которого будут добавляться разные товары + цена.

Вопрос как это обычно делается? Где хранить цены? Какие таблицы и связи делать?

Answer (score 0):

Туповатый вопрос наверное был.
Разобрался, нужно создать сущность и в этой сущности создать поле List со списком товаров и ценами